# Optimizing a one to many query that's using a subselect to paginate

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I was hoping to get some expert eyes over my query and see why I'm receiving different performance.

The problem I'm trying to solve is I need orders that can have one to many items. These orders need to be paginated.

To do this I've taken the following approach. I'm using a sub query to filter orders by the required item attributes. I'm then rejoining to the items to get their required fields. This means that when paginating I will not incorrectly filter order rows when there are orders with 2 or more items.

I'm seeing intermittently slow queries. The second time they are run they're much quicker. I presume this is because Postgres is loading indexes and such into memory?

I don't fully understand what is happening From the explain. It's looking like it needs to scan every order to see if they have an item that fits the subquery? I'm a bit confused by the following line. It's saying it needs to scan 286853 rows but also only 165?

```
Index Scan Backward using orders_created_at_idx on orders  (cost=0.42..2708393.65 rows=286853 width=301) (actual time=64.598..2114.676 rows=165 loops=1)
```

Is there a way to get Postgres to filter by the items first or am I reading this incorrectly and it is doing that already?

Query:

```
SELECT 
  "orders"."id_orders" as "orders.id_orders", 
  "items"."id_items" as "items"."id_items",
  ..., 
  orders.created_at, orders.updated_at 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    orders.id_orders,
    orders.created_at,
    orders.updated_at
  FROM orders 
  WHERE orders.status in ('completed','pending') AND 
  (
    SELECT fk_vendor_id FROM items
    WHERE (
      items.fk_order_id = orders.id_orders AND
      items.fk_vendor_id = '0012800001YVccUAAT' AND
      items.fk_offer = '0060I00000RAKFYQA5' AND
      items.status IN ('completed','cancelled')
    ) LIMIT 1
  ) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY orders.created_at DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 150
) as orders INNER JOIN items ON items.fk_order_id = orders.id_orders;
```

1st explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1417.11..2311.77 rows=67 width=1705) (actual time=2785.221..17025.325 rows=17 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=1416.68..1888.77 rows=50 width=301) (actual time=2785.216..17024.918 rows=15 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using orders_created_at_idx on orders  (cost=0.42..2708393.65 rows=286853 width=301) (actual time=1214.013..17024.897 rows=165 loops=1)
              Filter: ((status = ANY ('{completed,pending}'::orders_status_enum[])) AND ((SubPlan 1) IS NOT NULL))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 313631
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.047..0.047 rows=0 loops=287719)
                      ->  Index Scan using items_fk_order_id_index on items items_1  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.047..0.047 rows=0 loops=287719)
                            Index Cond: (fk_order_id = orders.id_orders)
                            Filter: ((status = ANY ('{completed,cancelled}'::items_status_enum[])) AND (fk_vendor_id = '0012800001YVccUAAT'::text) AND (fk_offer = '0060I00000RAKFYQA5'::text))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  ->  Index Scan using items_fk_order_id_index on items  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=1404) (actual time=0.002..0.026 rows=1 loops=15)
        Index Cond: (fk_order_id = orders.id_orders)
Planning time: 1.791 ms
Execution time: 17025.624 ms
(15 rows)
```

2nd explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1417.11..2311.77 rows=67 width=1705) (actual time=115.659..2114.739 rows=17 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=1416.68..1888.77 rows=50 width=301) (actual time=115.654..2114.691 rows=15 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using orders_created_at_idx on orders  (cost=0.42..2708393.65 rows=286853 width=301) (actual time=64.598..2114.676 rows=165 loops=1)
              Filter: ((status = ANY ('{completed,pending}'::orders_status_enum[])) AND ((SubPlan 1) IS NOT NULL))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 313631
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=287719)
                      ->  Index Scan using items_fk_order_id_index on items items_1  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=287719)
                            Index Cond: (fk_order_id = orders.id_orders)
                            Filter: ((status = ANY ('{completed,cancelled}'::items_status_enum[])) AND (fk_vendor_id = '0012800001YVccUAAT'::text) AND (fk_offer = '0060I00000RAKFYQA5'::text))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  ->  Index Scan using items_fk_order_id_index on items  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=1404) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=15)
        Index Cond: (fk_order_id = orders.id_orders)
Planning time: 2.011 ms
Execution time: 2115.052 ms
(15 rows)
```

Order indexes:

```
"cart_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_orders)
"orders_legacy_id_uindex" UNIQUE, btree (legacy_id_orders)
"orders_transaction_key_uindex" UNIQUE, btree (transaction_key)
"orders_created_at_idx" btree (created_at)
"orders_customer_email_idx" gin (customer_email gin_trgm_ops)
"orders_customer_full_name_idx" gin (customer_full_name gin_trgm_ops)
Referenced by:
TABLE "items" CONSTRAINT "items_fk_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (fk_order_id) REFERENCES orders(id_orders) ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "items_log" CONSTRAINT "items_log_fk_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (fk_order_id) REFERENCES orders(id_orders)
```

Items indexes:

```
"items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_items)
"items_fk_vendor_id_booking_number_unique" UNIQUE, btree (fk_vendor_id, booking_number) WHERE legacy_id_items IS NULL
"items_legacy_id_uindex" UNIQUE, btree (legacy_id_items)
"items_transaction_key_uindex" UNIQUE, btree (transaction_key)
"items_booking_number_index" btree (booking_number)
"items_fk_order_id_index" btree (fk_order_id)
"items_fk_vendor_id_index" btree (fk_vendor_id)
"items_status_index" btree (status)

Foreign-key constraints:
"items_fk_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (fk_order_id) REFERENCES orders(id_orders) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Comment: My own understanding is somewhat limited but I would head along the direction that the "Index Scan Backward" line you pointed out is what the optimiser expected to return for the query vs what it actually returned. Have a look at query hints, see if you can tell the quiet planet that you are only returning a few rows from the orders_created_at_idx table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in execution times is probably really the effect of caching. You could use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to see how many pages are found in the database cache.

To make your query more readable, you should rewrite

```
WHERE (
   SELECT fk_vendor_id FROM items
   WHERE (
     items.fk_order_id = orders.id_orders AND
     items.fk_vendor_id = '0012800001YVccUAAT' AND
     items.fk_offer = '0060I00000RAKFYQA5' AND
     items.status IN ('completed','cancelled')
   ) LIMIT 1
) IS NOT NULL
```

to

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM items
    WHERE items.fk_order_id = orders.id_orders
      AND items.fk_vendor_id = '0012800001YVccUAAT'
      AND items.fk_offer = '0060I00000RAKFYQA5'
      AND items.status IN ('completed','cancelled')
   )
```

The best thing you could do to speed up the query is to create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON items(fk_order_id, fk_vendor_id, fk_offer);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Laurenz. I'll test out adding the multiple index. As far as the subquery goes, am I right in presuming that SQL is smart enough to limit the orders scanned by filtering the items first? Or is it checking each order to see if it has valid items?

Comment: With a `[NOT] EXISTS` clause, scanning `items` will stop as soon as the first result is found.

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense. Correct me if I'm wrong but this is how I think the query is computed. First the subplan is processed and a set of items is found. Next each order that has a foreign key to the items from the subplan is ordered and a subset is returned based off the limit and offset. Then the join happens. I'm just trying to confirm that whats in my head is correct and the subplan is done first to filter the orders.

Comment: Almost. The plan is created before execution starts. A row is scanned from `orders_created_at_idx`. If the corresponding table row passes the filter, the subplan is executed and scans `items items_1` for a match. If a match is found, `items` is scanned for matching rows and result rows are formed. This process repeats until no more rows are found. PostgreSQL does not materialize the whole result set, it sends every result row as soon as it is available.

Comment: Ah okay, so if there is generally only a small amount of items that will match the subquery, say 100 out of 300,000 rows, it would be more performant to write a query that first filtered on the items and then joined back to the orders?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have the correct index on `items`, the inner side of the join will be fast as lightning, no matter how big the table is. I believe that PostgreSQL is choosing the correct plan here. But, generally speaking, it never hurts to add contitions that filter out rows before the table is joined, particularly with hash joins.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Thanks for all the info.

Comment: I get what you mean about it being faster. If you looked up only the items you wouldn't know the state of the order. So, filtering on order status is impossible until you do the join. With the above query you already have the correct orders and your new index will make looking up the items very quick. If you didn't care about order state and didn't need to order by created_at date then you could simply look up the items and join with orders.